# Processing sketch does not work on various web browsers

Tags: html, processing, processing.js

I have a processing sketch that works perfectly when run on `Processing 2.1.2`. I tried to embed it in a web page a while back with `processing.js` and it worked pretty well. Then, a few months later, when I check to see my sketch again, it does not work. Currently, it does not work on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Internet Explorer. It works only on Chrome on `iOS 7.1.2`(weirdly enough). A few months ago it was working on all those browsers.

[Here](http://studio.sketchpad.cc/sp/pad/view/Q6iN1RBgE7/rev.2) is the code (NOT working on sketchpad as well).

And here is what the sketch should look like after a while:
[image: And here is what the sketch should look like after a while]

And [here](http://www.iremaltan.com/test2.html) is the original web page that this is embedded in, with the following `html` code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Irem Altan | coming soon</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/processing.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas data-processing-sources="pde/imageTest.pde"></canvas>
        <p>experiments with processing...</p>
        <p><a href="http://behance.net/iremaltan">behance</a> <em>|</em> <a href="http://irem-altan.deviantart.com">deviantart</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me also include the original code:

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 563);
  String url = "http://iremaltan.com/pde/robb2/data/robb.jpg";
  img  = loadImage(url, "jpg");
  img.resize(1000, 563);
  img.loadPixels();
}

void draw() {
  int initPix = (int) random(1000*563);
  int init  = (int) grayRetriever(initPix);
  for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    int numPix = (int) random(1000*563);
    int num = (int) grayRetriever(numPix);
    if ( num<init || random(0,1)>float(num)/float(init)){
      float x = numPix % 1000;
      float y = numPix/1000;
     // println(x," ",y);
      point(x,y);
    }

  }
}

float grayRetriever(int pix){
  float r = red(img.pixels[pix]);
  float g = green(img.pixels[pix]);
  float b = blue(img.pixels[pix]);

  float gray = (r+g+b)/3;

  return(gray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't work in Processing either, because you scoped the `firstTime` and `img` variables to inside `setup()`. Once you hit `draw()` they are completely lost (and should be).

Move them out, and preload that image you're using:

```
/* @pjs preload="http://iremaltan.com/robbsmall.jpg"; */

boolean firstTime = true;
PImage img = loadImage("http://iremaltan.com/robbsmall.jpg"); 

void setup(){
  size(1000, 558);
}

[rest of your code]
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it works locally on processing, but does not work on sketchpad. It's the first time I've used sketchpad, so it's possible you have looked at some version that does not already work. I've edited my post to include the original code as well. Since I declare the `img` variable outside `setup()` I guess there is no scope problem. I don't know why it keeps on working locally, but stops working when embedded into a browser. I apologize for any confusion I may have caused by omitting the original code.

Comment: that `/* ... */` is not a comment. It's a processing.js [preload instruction](http://processingjs.org/reference/preload) and you *need* to have it in your sketch source.

Comment: I've tried that, and it still doesn't work: http://iremaltan.com/pde/pointillism2.pde

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem, it's an opinion: what does the browser console say when you try it with the preload? because the only error I get is that the image is being loaded from a domain that doesn't specify its images are allowed to be tinkered with, so Processing can't do anything with/to it.

Comment: Alright, so let me rephrase by saying it's not doing what it's expected to do, which is re-creating the image by generating random dots. I get the same error message, but I don't quite understand how to fix the problem. If I shouldn't be able to load the image from the domain, why does the sketch work when run in Processing? I have another sketch that runs without that error: http://www.iremaltan.com/test3.html (but cannot resize the image).

Comment: Processing and Processing.js obey different rules when it comes to I/O and the likes. Processing can do whatever it likes. Processing.js can only do what browsers are allowed to do, so has more restrictions. Just showing the image might work fine, accessing the pixels can be forbidden.

Comment: What can I do to get the sketch to work on the browser as it does within Processing?

Comment: images on same-origin (so on the same domain as the sketch is running), or on a domain that sends a CORS header indicating the image may be modified by the client. Option 1 is by far the easiest.

Comment: ...which pretty much means in order for this to run it should be running from a web server rather than a direct file call to the html file. Correct?

Comment: correct, always test web pages that "load other things" from a web server (either remote or local. You have a million options for running a single-command localhost server like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` or `http-server` installed with npm, etc).